# Python type annotations: Any way to annotate a property?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations

I'm defining a Python class:

```
class Foo:
    bar = property(lambda self: Bar(self))
```

I want to annotate the `bar` property to say that it contains an item of class `Bar`. Is there an accepted way of doing that? I know that this is valid Python syntax:

```
bar: Bar = property(lambda self: Bar(self))
```

But is this an accepted way of annotating a property?

Comment: notice that property can take a [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) string

Answer (score 10):

If you want to be safe, simply refactor it into using the decorator form and specify a return value:

```
class Foo:
    @property
    def bar(self) -> Bar:
        return Bar(self)
```

this is also the form used in [`typeshed`](https://github.com/python/typeshed) which collects stubs annotating the standard library and also smoothly passes through `mypy`.

As for variable annotation syntax of Python 3.6, the form:

```
bar: Bar = property(lambda self: Bar(self))
```

is currently acceptable when checking with `mypy`.

Comment: This doesn't work: "def bar(self) -> Bar:"  is not valid code!

Comment: @z0mbi3 I'm not really sure what you mean? That is valid code.

Answer (score -6):

In such situation. I may well draw upon the design of other languages.
Take Scala for example:

```scala
object A {
    def property: Int = { println("property called"); 1 }
}

A.property
// property called
// res: Int = 1
```

Scala language has *Uniform Access Principle* in mind:

> there should be no difference from user between accessing with an attribute, precomputed property, or parameterless method.

A computable property in theory is just a function that has zero parameters, e.g. `()=>T` in Scala. While from user viewpoint it should just be a constant property with type `T`.

---

Back to the question, if we borrow the principle(it's good in my opinion), the type should just the return type -- `Bar`, not the `property` decorator type in Python.